# How to store value from JSpinner of Date format into a JodaTime variable?

Tags: java, swing, jodatime, jspinner

I got a custom class that contains JodaTime's LocalDate variable to hold a date.
My swing application has a JSpinner with Date model. 
I made a button click event so that the date gets stored inside an object's LocalDate data member.
Problem is compiler gives me the IllegalArgumentException.

I tried to use LocalDate.parse(spinnerDate.getVAlue().toString()) but is not working.
Also tried to switch to using DateTime type but same result was given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that an `IllegalArgumentException` is something that would be generated at *runtime*, I doubt you're getting a 'compiler' error.

If you don't care what the timezone or chronology is (probable), you could always use `new LocalDate(spinnerDate.getValue());`.

Otherwise, consider implementing your own spinner that can store `LocalDate`s natively, or switching to using a pre-defined list of `LocalDate`s in a `SpinnerListModel`.

Comment: Hmm. The `new LocalDate(spinnerDate.getValue());` worked.
I guess `.toString` was the one causing the runtime error.
Thanks!

Comment: You'd probably need to run through an entire formatter to get the string version to work - the `LocalDate` will be expecting a particular format.  But that's not necessary here - you have a valid date object to begin with.